# Loop through a table for parameters

Tags: ssis

I pull a series of 4 sets (accounts referred, carried over to the next month, starts and closed accounts) of data every month through an SSIS package and the records are then stored in a table for reporting.  I use six parameters to pull this data.  My source data can change but should not.  To capture these changes, I need to pull months data as well as the past 3 months.  I am looking to set up the parameters in a SQL table to then loop through the values and pull all 4 months at one time.  Is this possible or is there another scenario that would fulfill this requirement?

Thank you in advance,
Mike

Comment: Yes, this can probably be done but we'd need some more information about how you're envisioning this working. Your parameters - I presume they're date ranges or something to help the package identify the data sets? Does parameter 1 apply to all 4 sets or does p1 go with set1, p2&3 to set2, etc

Comment: Basically - I have 6 parameters and yes all dates.  Start Date, End Date (for the reporting month), FY Start Date and End Date, Last mo End Date and Next MO Start Date.  All dates are needed because of how the source data is formatted.   All dates would be a row in the SQL table.  So when pulling the data for April, Jan through April will be pulled.  The download date and status (starts, closed, etc) are updated to each record (SQL task) after each data flow is complete.